# What is a brownian bridge’s quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I know that given a Brownian motion $W(t)$, its quadratic variation is 
$$[W,W](t) = t$$

Then for a brownian bridge, $X(t) := W(t) - \frac{t}{T} W(T) $, what is its quadratic variation?

Comment: Use the fact that quadratic variation is bilinear and that the process $t\to \frac{t}{T}W_T$ has finite variation which kills all covariations with that term. You should end up with something eerily familiar.

Comment: @JamesYang is it also $t$?

Comment: Yes! In general if you have $X_t = Y_t + A_t$ where $A_t$ is a finite variation process, $\langle X \rangle_t = \langle Y \rangle_t$, where $\langle \cdot \rangle_t$ is quadratic variation, by the same argument.

Comment: thanks so much@JamesYang